# How to have sum of values sum to 1 in geom_freqpoly()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As an example, we can use `geom_freqpoly()` to examine how `hp` varies by `cyl` in the `mtcars` data.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x=hp, color=cyl) +
  geom_freqpoly(mapping = aes(y = after_stat(ncount)), bins=5)
```

[image]

Using `after_stat(ncount)`, I can make each line be normalized between 0 and 1. However, is there a way to have it so that the sum of all the lines at any point is equal to 1? i.e., at any value of `hp`, the red, green, and blue lines add to one -- representing the estimated proportion of each `cyl` type at that value of `hp`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with `position = "fill"`, though it looks confusing with lines and is better represented as a filled geom using the same statistical transformation as `geom_freqpoly`

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = hp, fill =c yl) +
  stat_bin(bins = 5, position = "fill", geom = "area")
```

[image]

Compare this to the same result using an unfilled `geom_freqpoly`

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = hp, color = cyl) +
  geom_freqpoly(position = "fill", bins = 5)
```

[image]

I think this is harder to follow.

Another alternative to `geom_freqpoly` would be `geom_density`, which permits more visually appealing representations of similar information:

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = hp, fill = cyl) +
  geom_density(position = "fill", alpha = 0.5, color = "white", lwd = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(50, 200)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(y = "Relative density")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>